# How to start drag immediately using UIDragInteraction?

Tags: ios, swift, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm using UIDragInteraction and it works perfectly.

```
let dragInteraction = UIDragInteraction(delegate: self)
myView.addInteraction(dragInteraction)
dragInteraction.isEnabled = true
```

As intended, the drag starts when I make a long press on myView. I now want to change this behavior. Instead of long press, I want the drag to start immediately on touching myView and moving my finger?

I've tried using a pan gesture to initiate the move but I don't know how to get the dragInteraction to start.

```
let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panAction))
panGesture.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1
panGesture.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1
panGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
panGesture.delaysTouchesBegan = false
myView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
```

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Decrease the long-press duration right after adding the drag interaction:

```
myView.gestureRecognizers?.compactMap({ $0 as? UILongPressGestureRecognizer}).forEach { recognizer in
    recognizer.minimumPressDuration = .leastNonzeroMagnitude
}
```

Comment: This works well !.... I put it in viewDidLoad() to modifiy the the trigger period for two views (to drag both ways), , where the view was a UITableView and another was a UICollectionView, and it made it very quick to trigger. .... (Note: The default longpress time is 0.5). I wasn't getting the result I wanted from this less concise approach: if let longPress = view?.gestureRecognizers?.first(where: { $0 is UILongPressGestureRecognizer }) as? UILongPressGestureRecognizer { longPress.minimumPressDuration = 0.1 } –

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem to be possible at the moment with the standard drag and drop implementation.

You could lower the `minimumPressDuration` of the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` associated with the `UIDragInteraction` though. Further explanation for this can be found in this answer: [set minimumPressDuration for UIDragInteraction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50394745/3336681)

In addition to that you can always implement your own drag and drop interaction by using gesture recognizers, etc.. This might of course be tedious and not what you want.