# Modify hold timing for onDrag SwiftUI event to trigger

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, drag-and-drop

With SwiftUI views, is there a way to change the hold duration needed for the [`onDrag`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/ondrag(_:)) event to trigger? There seems to be a hack to do this with `UIKit`, as seen in [ability to shorten UIDragInteraction's long press timing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48175672/ability-to-shorten-uidraginteractions-long-press-timing). However, I couldn't figure out how to make this work with SwiftUI.

Is there a straightforward way to do this? Following the linked question, would I need some wrappers to modify the UIKit `gestureRecognizers` property on the SwiftUI view?